# convert obj std to model laravel DB::query

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I was wandering how to go about converting my results from `obj std` to a custom Eloquent Model from a `DB::query()->get()` method.

Example Code:

```
$results  = DB::table('listings')->get();
```

Now how do I get each `$result` to be of a `new Listing()` class.

Comment: If you want an array of `Listings`, why not use `Listings::all()`?

Comment: I was going to use that but I couldnt work out how to specify the table as _l_ example: `DB::table('listings as l')`. I couldnt work out how to do that in the `Listings` Builder... I also heard that `DB` is faster.

Comment: Why do you need to alias the table name? If you need to build a more complex query then give more details. If not, I doubt using `DB` instead of `Eloquent` will show any real performance benefit (to be sure you can try profiling your app to see if it really makes a difference in your case, but a good rule of thumb is to _optimize when you actually need to_).

Comment: yer ok sure. I only aliased the table name because i was referencing it quite a lot in the query. But yer your right. Ill just remove all the aliased instances within the query and build it with the Listing model. Thanks for the help. that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already established in the comments, if you want the model, use the model. However you can still use the table alias. Either specify it in the model if you want to always use it:

```
protected $table = 'listings AS l';
```

Or you can specify it on the fly with `from()`:

```
Listing::from('listings AS l')->where(...)->join(...)->get();
```

Comment: ahh this is perfect. thanks for your answer. exactly what I was after.